# return statement in finally block

Tags: javascript, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

In [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Exception_Handling_Statements) its stated,

> If the finally block returns a value, **this value becomes the return value of the entire try-catch-finally production**, regardless of any return statements in the try and catch blocks:

So I try to execute the following code,

```
function an(){
    var r = try{
        throw 1;
    } catch(e){
        console.log("Caught: %o", e);
    } finally {
        return 2;
    }
    console.log("r=%o", r);
    return 3;
}
```

It does not work. Throws a syntax error.

```
SyntaxError: syntax error

    var r = try{
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: u can not have the `r=` thing..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is simply that you're trying to assign a try statement to a variable. As far as I'm aware (and I'm no JS expert) you can't do that. It's a statement, not an expression.

I believe this is entirely separate to what happens with return values.

Try putting your try/catch/finally statement into a separate function, and call that instead, assigning the result to r:

```
function foo() {
    try {
        throw 1;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Caught: %o", e);
    } finally {
        return 2;
    }
}

var r = foo();
console.log("r=%o", r);
```

In Chrome's Javascript console, that gives:

```
Caught: 1
r=2
```

EDIT: I agree that the term "production" in the docs is a bit confusing here. According to comments, it's technically accurate - but that doesn't stop it from being confusing, of course. I suspect that in most cases "function" would be clearer, probably less definitively accurate.

Comment: I am also guessing its a try-catch is a statement, hence no return value. But the statement from MDN is quite confusing.

Comment: @GenghisKhan: Yes, it's a statement rather than an expression. I suspect that in most cases it would be better to just say "function" instead of "production" here, but there may well be corner cases where that's not correct either.

Comment: @JonSkeet: no, "production" is correct. The thing is, JS productions, including statements, do have values, you just cannot assign these to variables.

Comment: @thg435 so `var x=1;` is a production that returns `undefined`?

Comment: @GenghisKhan: it returns a "completion" equal to `(normal, empty, empty)` (http://es5.github.io/#x12.2).

Answer (score 3):

What they mean is this:

```
function an() {
    try {
        throw 999;
        return "in try";
    } catch(e) {
        return "in catch";
    } finally {
        return "in finally";
    }
    return "in func";
}

console.log(an()) // in finally
```

JS ignores all `return` statements, except the one in the finally block.

Comment: I find this the most concise and accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong. You have syntax error. `try` block dont returns anything.

```
function an(){
var r;// <---- here
try{// <----- here
    throw 1;
} catch(e){
    console.log("Caught: %o", e);
} finally {
    return 2;
}
console.log("r=%o", r);
return 3;
}
```